# Loading prefixed parquet files from s3 - Suspicious paths

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, emr, amazon-emr

I have a set of prefixed (as per S3 performance recommendations) parquet files I want to load in spark (using Amazon EMR 5.11.1) but

1. the time taken to list the set of files matching the glob is much slower than non-prefixed files, can this be improved?
2. how can the following error be avoided?

---

```
 val df = spark.read.parquet("s3://bucket/????/analytics")

java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Conflicting directory
     structures detected. Suspicious paths:?
        s3://bucket/4a73/analytics
        s3://bucket/8163/analytics

If provided paths are partition directories, please set "basePath" in the options of the data source to specify the root directory of the table. If there are multiple root directories, please load them separately and then union them.
  at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:170)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.PartitioningUtils$.parsePartitions(PartitioningUtils.scala:132)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.PartitioningUtils$.parsePartitions(PartitioningUtils.scala:97)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.PartitioningAwareFileIndex.inferPartitioning(PartitioningAwareFileIndex.scala:153)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.partitionSpec(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.PartitioningAwareFileIndex.partitionSchema(PartitioningAwareFileIndex.scala:50)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:134)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:353)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:559)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:543)
  ... 48 elided
```

Comment: I think it is recommended to use hash prefixes in S3 object keys if you are expecting loads over 100 queries/second. It would indeed be much easier to have single path from where to read all the parquet files, e.g. `s3://bucket/analytics`. If you aren't truly over 100 QPS, you may want to reconsider your directory structure, unless there is another requirement for it?

Answer (score -2):

**Instead of s3 you can use the s3a.
This may be work out for you.**

1.You'll also need the hadoop-aws 2.7.1 JAR on the classpath. 
This JAR contains the

```
class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.
```

2.In spark.properties you can  some settings  like this:

```
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key=ACCESSKEY  
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key=SECRETKEY
```

Comment: On Amazon EMR s3:// is the binding to Amazon's own (closed source) connector. I believe its the only one whay support.

Comment: This might help with the performance, although I suspect not with the error message above.